# How to increment a counter multiple times from 1 input

Tags: flipflop

My circuit is for a quiz scoreboard and when the player gets 5 correct answers in a row they are awarded 3 bonus points. I have 2 separate d type flip flop binary counters to do this, one for the score without bonus points and one for the score with the bonus points to use as an output to the scoreboard. How would I go about making it so when the score without bonus points reaches 5 the score with bonus points is incremented by 3 instead of just 1? [image: My circuit]

Comment: This sounds like a job for some kind of FSM, which is best designed using the formal methods for designing FSMs.

Comment: Unless this project is purely for learning to design digital logic, use a microcontroller instead. Cheaper and easier.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Unfortunately its university work so I cant use microcontrollers as much as I wish I could

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not familiar with FSMs what exactly are they?

Comment: With no debouncing on the buttons your players will be already getting plenty of extra points :)

Comment: FSM=Finite State Machine.

Comment: @Finbarr not really much point debouncing switches for an example but thank you for your extremely useful comment

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a ripple counter which by design only increments by one. I would use a register and an adder. Make them long enough to store the maximum count that you need.

One input of the adder would be from the register that holds the count value. The other input comes from logic that determines the value to be added for a particular button.

The pushbuttons should be debounced first to ensure that you have a clean signal.

When the pushbutton is pressed it should set the value into the adder, the pushbutton release would cause the register to load the value from the output of the adder.

With this approach it is straightforward to add any value you wish for a pushbutton press. You can even make it remove points by setting the value from the pushbutton to the 2's complement of the value.